# Property 'Clip' does not support values of type 'EllipseGeometry'

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

In Windows Phone 8.1 I used 'EllipseGeometry' but it's not available in WinRT (or Universal app). Can anyone tell me it's alternative way

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="myCanvas" >
        <Canvas.Clip>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="114.5,114.5" RadiusX="114.5" RadiusY="114.5" />
        </Canvas.Clip>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

The error is: **Property 'Clip' does not support values of type 'EllipseGeometry'**

My problem is that where should I look for an alternative of EllipseGeometry?

Comment: Would `ImageBrush` on an actual Ellipse be an option?

Comment: What end result are you looking for? Windows.UI.Xaml supports only rectangular clipping so if you want round you'll need to do something other than clip. In addition to Chris' suggestion of filling an ellipse, you can few possibilities are to mask out the unclipped area by overlaying a filled geometry missing your ellipse or an image with a transparent area for the ellipse.

Comment: @ChrisW. No I can't use it I am trying to make a hole in the canvas..

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT I am actually trying to make a hole in the canvas, so that canvas is capable of displaying several controls like clock etc. The thing is that it was working fine until I shifted to UApp

Comment: I just noticed that on the code side I can access it (Windows::UI::Xaml::Media   ---> EllipseGeometry) but not on the XAML side. - Only RectangleGeometry is available on XAML side. I think something is broken here!!

Comment: Wafers, see my answer, It worked for me successfully in windows phone 8.1 app

Answer (score 0):

In my windows phone 8.1 App, I used following instead of EllipseGeometry, Worked.

```
<Ellipse>
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="YourImage.png"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```